# ENOENT (No such file or directory) android

Tags: android, file, directory

I have checked all questions relating to this on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to help me. My program used to run perfectly fine, then I deleted my AVD and when I ran it again it gave me that error when trying to create my database folder.

I have the read and write permissions in the manifest file, is there anything else I can supply you with?

Any help will be appreciated, I don't think its my code since all I did was recreate my AVD, but I might have just been lucky the past 2 weeks

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2)
    {
       DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
    }
    else
    {

       DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.mContext = context;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets

copyDataBase();

mDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist)
    {

       mDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");

        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
           throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");           
        }
    }
}
//Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());

    this.getReadableDatabase();

    return dbFile.exists();
}

//Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

//Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,         SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}
```